# Node, async, and callback on all tasks finished within the iterator function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

So I'm performing a task in a async.map collection, the iterator function performs several asynchronous tasks before it performs a task on all the data collected by the asynchronous tasks.

A quick pseudo example of this would look like:

```
var accts=//array of accounts fechted from mongodb
async.map(accts,function(acct,callback){
   var likes=0;
   http.get(acct.facebook,function(err,resp){/*add fan count to likes*/});
   http.get(acct.twitter,function(err,resp){/*add followers to likes*/});
   //mongoose Model named artist
   artist.update({_id:acct._id},{fans:likes},function(err,acctsUpdate){});
}
```

My confusion lies in the fact that updating mongodb will probably happen before both of the async task are finished, therefore breaking my application. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Please note that I do understand that my http.get() requests are not valid API calls to facebook and twitter API, these are just pseudo example bits.

Comment: Wait, it may have just clicked in my mind. Should I embed a async.parallel control flow to callback? Or is this similar to creating functions in a loop? Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar using async.waterfall and async.map. Hope this helps

```
async.waterfall([

  function(callback){
    request.get('/api/fancy/', function(err, r, body) {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      callback(null, data);
    });

  },

  function(accts, callback){
    async.map(accts, _insertAcct, function(err, results){
      if (err) return done(err);
      done(null, results);
    });


    function _insertAcct(acct, _cb){
      if (!acct)
        return _cb(new Error('No acct data'));

      // save the acct to the db, using mongoskin
      db.collection('acct').save(audit, {upsert: true}, function(err, result){;
        if (err) return _cb(err);
        _cb(null, result)
      });
    }

  }
], function(err, results){
  // 
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You're answer did help my implementation, though it was a bit different.